# Running an F# program in VS Code using the Ionide plugin

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, f#, centos, ionide

I opened my project directory in VS Code.

I set a breakpoint and pressed F5. Now I get

> command 'csharp.coreclrAdapterExecutableCommand' not found

What should I install to make it work?

UPDATE: this is under Centos 7 and I did install .net core runtime 3.1 and .net core sdk 3.1 and the ionide-fsharp plugin